# When will Ethereum switch to Proof of Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper, serenity

What is the latest estimation of when will the switch to PoS happen?

Last time the question was asked about 6 months ago, the answer was mid-2016, which is just around the corner. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802343/when-will-ethereum-switch-to-proof-of-stake.

Comment: I think no one knows... even its creators...

Comment: At least the difficulty bomb makes the issue a pressing one...

Comment: Moving targets and not a good fit for StackExchange. It's better to ask on another site like the [Ethereum reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it's (nearly) ready ! 
Ethereum is highly innovative, and developed in 'agile' mode. Even the [content of the releases](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/42h380/can_someone_explain_the_next_steps_in_the/) may be swapped or changed. So, that kind of product is released when the end is in sight...
The latest roadmap seems [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UuLmIG_IGWNtaari4UbLdCo9anRxE9m2s-HTya8fTTw/edit#heading=h.mzoeaw700ym5), making **Mist(Metropolis) by early2017**. 
And Casper PoS (Serenity) should be next.

Comment: The second link is dead.