# Is it worth to mine Ethereum today?

Tags: mining

Worth buying a pc with 2 GPU's in a crossfire to mine Ethereum? I plan to spend ~$1000 on that pc.

What client to use? What os is better to use? Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether)

Comment: Which GPU model?

Answer (score 2):

Some calculations to work out the profitability are available from:

- [Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether)
- [What's the best Hardware for Mining Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/whats-the-best-hardware-for-mining-ether)

The normal client is `geth` to run the Ethereum node and `ethminer` to run the mining calculations. Note that Ethereum will be moving to proof of stake at some unknown time in the future and your GPUs will not be useful for mining the Ethereum blockchain any more - see [When will Ethereum switch to Proof of Stake?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/when-will-ethereum-switch-to-proof-of-stake).

Comment: I agree with the above but would that that many GPUs will retain reasonable resale value. So depending on then the PoS conversion takes place you can sell your GPUs and recover some of your costs

Comment: You just have to sell it before the resale price drops when all the other Ethereum miners sell theirs :-)